# Bitcoin Core download

Tags: bitcoin-core

How long it normally takes to download full database of blocks in Bitcoin Core
I have fast internet, but after 72 hours I'am only on 50 percent.

Thank you

Comment: It means it takes 72 hours to download 75 GB. That's fine.

Comment: OK, thanks, I saw some similar questions and answers, but after I posted this massage.... Appreciate your time.